# How often do I need to eat water-soluble vitamins?

Tags: micronutrients

Preciser phrasing of the question:
Do I need to consume the daily recommended dose of water-soluble vitamins every single day? Or is it sufficient if my consumption averages to the daily dose over a longer timeframe (and what timeframe would that be)?

I am aware that:

- fat-soluble vitamins can be stored for a long time (months, possibly even years in some cases).
- water-soluble vitamins can (with the exception of B12) only be stored for a short time.

However, I have not found any clear answer to how short the "short time" for water-soluble vitamins is (a single day? A week? Not at all?).
Answers I found are usually vague or inconsistent with each other (and also not sourced):

> "it is recommended that you replenish your stores of water-soluble
> vitamins every few days" [[1](https://www.sharecare.com/health/vitamins-supplements/how-water-soluble-vitamins-absorbed)]
>
> "you should try to get them regularly from your diet." [[2](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/water-soluble-vitamins#b1)]
>
> "water-soluble vitamins dissolve in water and are not stored by the body. Since they are eliminated in urine, we require a continuous daily supply in our diet." [[3](https://extension.colostate.edu/topic-areas/nutrition-food-safety-health/water-soluble-vitamins-b-complex-and-vitamin-c-9-312/)]

Background: I am currently trying to eat healthier than I used to. One thing I want to track is my vitamin intake to ensure that I do not develop deficiencies.

However, I am not sure how granularly I have to keep up with *daily* recommended doses.

Example: The German Nutrition Society recommends 110mg of Vitamin C daily for me [[4](https://www.dge.de/wissenschaft/referenzwerte/vitamin-c/)]. Does this mean that I actualy need 110mg every single day in order to not develop a deficiency long-term? Or is it sufficient if I track my intake, e.g., on a weekly basis (requiring 770mg per week)?

I am aware that there are also differing opinions about the actual amount per day that is needed (e.g., 110mg in Germany, 90mg in the US [[5](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminC-Consumer/)]) but this is out-of-scope of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to get 100% of [Recommended Dietary Allowance (RDA)](http://nationalacademies.org/hmd/~/media/Files/Report%20Files/2019/DRI-Tables-2019/6_DRIValues_Summary.pdf?la=en) of every water-soluble vitamin every single day. It depends on the vitamin, but you can safely assume it is enough you get about 7 RDAs of each in a week.

It is often said that water-soluble vitamins (B complex and C) are not stored in the body, but this is not exactly true. There is always a "pool" of vitamins in the liver or somewhere else from which they are available for few weeks at least.

There is no known vitamin deficiency that would develop in a healthy well-nourished adult within a week of abstinence from that vitamin.

Time in which symptoms can develop after stopping or *greatly* reducing vitamin intake:

- **Vitamin B1 (thiamin):** within 12 weeks ([WHO](https://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/en/thiamine_in_emergencies_eng.pdf))
- **Vitamin B2 (riboflavin):** several months ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/nutritional-disease/Vitamin-K#ref848957))
- **Vitamin B3 (niacin):** in 4 months ([WHO](https://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/en/pellagra_prevention_control.pdf))
- **Vitamin B9 (folate):** within a month ; **vitamin B12 (cobalamin):** in 3-5 years ([Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/204066-overview#showall))
- **Vitamin C:** within 1-2 months ([NIH-ODS](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminC-HealthProfessional/), [WHO](https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/42716/9241546123.pdf))

> It requires weeks to months of undernutrition for deficiencies of
>   water-soluble vitamins (except vitamin B12) to develop, whereas
>   deficiencies of fat-soluble vitamins, and of vitamin B12, require more
>   than a year to develop due to larger body stores ([US Pharmacist](https://www.uspharmacist.com/article/vitamin-deficiencies-in-seniors)).

Comment: Difference between regulatory bodies/countries indicate that the numbers are largely arbitrary. Unless a real deficiency develops *much* lower doses are quite fine. Take VitC. USA: 90mg (was lower before) Germany 110mg (was lower before). Mean daily intake in Netherlands only 78mg, yet zero cases of scurvy…

Comment: I'm thinking all the time that RDAs are probably much greater than "minimal" and even "optimal" amounts. They pumped the RDA for potassium to 4.7 g/day, which is just unrealistic for many people.